# Read Raw Touch Input Events on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, multi-touch, android-sensors, hid

I've been doing some research to see if something like this is feasible, and I haven't come up with anything good yet. I would like to write an application that intercepts Android touch information (at some level).

I am looking into developing an app that monitors a user's touch events in the background. This sounds like a sinister keylogger or something, but it's actually for a pilot study to monitor activity (dexterity, etc) in aging people to try to predict cognitive decline (similar studies have been done which monitor typing dexterity). I don't really care (or want to know) what they're clicking on or anything, I'm more interested in (extracting) metrics like number of clicks, time between clicks, touch velocity, etc.

Any ideas if this is possible, and how to go about doing this? I'm not scared of the NDK or anything, and theoretically we will control the phones (at first), so rooting isn't entirely out of the question (if necessary). However, it'd be nice to avoid hacks like that if possible.

Any ideas of avenues to explore to proceed on this project?